# make things glow with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I don't know much about shaders or three.js, but I am trying to make things glow dynamically, kind of like if they were lights flicked on for a second then off. Right now I adjust the color saturation and lightness- it kind of works, but it doesn't look great to me. Is there something I can do with shaders, or some other way of modulating the colors to make this look better?

Answer (score 0):

There are some plugins onver THREE.js to do post-processing.

You can take a look at this [example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_advanced) it uses different post processing shaders. You can look at the source how to use it. The complete list of "official shaders" can be found [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples/js/shaders). Be careful some of them are not post-processing shaders, I think post-processing shaders all camr from the commit "Splitted ShaderExtras into individual files.").

If you want to try some of them (and some other filters) you can read this   [article](http://www.instructables.com/id/Instructables-Universe-in-Threejs/step12/Threejs-Post-processing-Effects-Dimming-Blurring/) and look at the demo [here](http://www.airtightinteractive.com/demos/js/shaders/preview/)

I don't really know what you mean by "glow" so I can't tell you which one is the best but if you have time you can learn GLSL and write your own shader that fits your requirements.